# Count popular tags with comma delimited field on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a comma delimited field on my table, it stores Tags like:

```
avengers, heroes, marvel, 2012, hulk, captain america
```

And i want to get the most used tags.

How can i do this on one single SELECT query?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - MySQL does not provide a function to split strings, for one thing. You need to normalize your data to achieve this in pure SQL.

Comment: Really? What do you think is the best way for this? Do i need to separately add the tags or what?

Comment: Instead of having a `tags` column with a comma-separated string, you'd need a `tags` table with id and value, and a join table that maps tags to your tagged objects table. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644330/best-structure-for-a-relational-database-with-articles-and-tags

Comment: @wpleet: Here's another one for you: [MySQL: Understanding mapping tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453462/mysql-understanding-mapping-tables), just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Half a decade has passed. Still, there *is* a way to do this. You can actually extract individual "terms" from a comma-separated list of terms in MySQL. It's incredibly nasty, and it requires knowing the maximum number of terms that will appear in any row. The SUBSTRING_INDEX() function is the key to it.

Let's say you never have more than five terms in a field. Then this query gets all your terms and orders them from most frequent to least.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), term FROM(
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Tags,','), ',',1), ',', -1)) term FROM Resources
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Tags,','), ',',2), ',', -1)) term FROM Resources
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Tags,','), ',',3), ',', -1)) term FROM Resources
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Tags,','), ',',4), ',', -1)) term FROM Resources
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Tags,','), ',',5), ',', -1)) term FROM Resources
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Tags,','), ',',6), ',', -1)) term FROM Resources
) terms
WHERE LENGTH(term) > 0
GROUP BY term
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You can just put more terms in the union if you have a maximum term count more than five.

Should you normalize? Yes you should normalize. Can you use this kind of query to create a normalized version of your table. Yes.