# Extracting values from (multiple) brackets in one string

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's what I would like to do with MySQL (MariaDB). I want to retrieve a substring of the contents between curly brackets (let's call them tags) in the column 'Case_Title'. My table looks like this.

**Table: cases**

```
| Case_ID | Case_Title                       | Department  |
|---------|----------------------------------|-------------|
| 7032389 | {RJ1} Not able to connect        | Consumer    |
| 7243040 | {RJ2}{ZO}{WAD} Connection issues | Business    |
| 7249910 | {O2A} No incoming mgs {WAD}      | Consumer    |
|---------|----------------------------------|-------------|
```

By searching Stack Overflow I came up with two options to retrieve these substrings.

**1 - Using regular expressions.** Since I'm on MariaDB so I can use *REGEXP_SUBSTR, REGEXP_INSTR, REGEXP_REPLACE*.

```
SELECT Case_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Case_title,'{(.*?)}') as 'Tag'
FROM cases
```

**2 - combinations of *SUBSTR()* and *INSTR()*.**

```
SELECT Case_ID, SUBSTR(Case_Title,INSTR(Case_Title,"{"), INSTR(Case_Title,"}") - INSTR(Case_Title,"{") + 1) as 'Tag'
FROM cases
```

Both options will output:

```
| Case_ID | Tag   |
|---------|-------|
| 7032389 | {RJ1} |
| 7243040 | {RJ2} |
| 7249910 | {O2A} |
|---------|-------|
```

However, the other 'tags' in the Case_Title are ignored. I just cannot seem to find a way to get the output like this:

```
| Case_ID | Tag   |
|---------|-------|
| 7032389 | {RJ1} |
| 7243040 | {RJ2} |
| 7243040 | {ZO}  |
| 7243040 | {WAD} |
| 7249910 | {O2A} |
| 7249910 | {WAD} |
|---------|-------|
```

Please note that I'd like to have new records/rows for each tag, rather than concatenating them like: `{RJ1},{ZO},{WAD}`. Also, I don't know in advance:

- how many tags a title will contain.
- where the tags are located in the Case_Title.
- if all tags are grouped together or if they're scattered across the Case_Title.
- the actual contents of the tag themselves.

Comment: I don't have time to do this as a full answer, but consider: Join your table to another table that is just a list of numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 ... (you can make it by union). Make the ON clause of the join a predicate where the `number` is <= the `length(case_title) - length(replace(case_title,'{',''))`. this is essentially the count of the number of times { occurrs so for the case title with 3 fields, the row should repeat itself 3 times. use substring / substring_index to cut case title up differently according to number, so one row has 3 fields,second row has 2 fields, third row has 1 field..

Comment: and use your regex match method - it's only picking the first field it finds per row, so cut the string up on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd substring_index (occurrence of) {, to remove fields from the second, third etc rows, before regex gets to see the value..

Comment: pps; you're going to need as many `numbers` rows as the maximum field count.. so if one of your case titles has 450 fields, you're going to need 450 numbers, that row will have to repeat itself 450 times.. etcetc

Comment: Those of us who aren't geniuses normalize our databases. Making valuable customer data subject to the whims of genius is not really ethical. That being said, read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144201/mysql-finding-the-most-frequently-used-words-in-a-comma-delimited-field/47144797#47144797 It explains how to extract comma-separated values. You can adapt it to your `{}` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of functions this works by first pivoting the data, separating them by `}{`, this then gets each value on its own line. From there I removed all values after the first `}`. Some concatenation was needed to restore lost brackets removed in the pivoting.

```
SELECT Case_ID,
CONCAT(substring_index(CASE WHEN RIGHT(CASE WHEN LEFT(tag,1) = '{' 
                                            THEN tag 
                                            ELSE CONCAT('{',tag) END,1) = '}' 
                            THEN CASE WHEN LEFT(tag,1) = '{' 
                                      THEN tag 
                                      ELSE CONCAT('{',tag) 
                                 END 
                            ELSE CONCAT(CASE WHEN LEFT(tag,1) = '{' 
                                             THEN tag 
                                             ELSE CONCAT('{',tag) 
                                        END,'}') 
                       END,'}',1),'}') AS tag
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Case_ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Case_Title, '}{', n), '}{', -1) tag
FROM (SELECT 1 n 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 5) n 
INNER JOIN cases ON CHAR_LENGTH(Case_Title)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Case_Title, '}{', ''))>=n-1) a
```

Input

```
Case_ID Case_Title                       Department
7032389 {RJ1} Not able to connect        Consumer
7243040 {RJ2}{ZO}{WAD} Connection issues Business
7249910 {O2A} No incoming mgs {WAD}      Consumer
```

Output

```
Case_ID tag
7032389 {RJ1}
7243040 {RJ2}
7249910 {O2A}
7243040 {ZO}
7243040 {WAD}
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fa9c13/94/0

Comment: Works like a charm, except for Case_ID 7249910. It just outputs {O2A} and ignores the {WAD} at the end of the case title.

Comment: The reason is that it only splits the string at `'}{'`. Therefore I first change the string with `REGEXP_REPLACE(Case_Title,'}(.*?){','}{')`