# Mysql Search with both side comma separated values

Tags: mysql

What i am facing issue here is i have data in CSV like 1,2,3,4,58,12,3 and i want to search for any data matching with any of these ids in table the table has data like 2,3,4,1,22,3,4,111,2

i have been using this

```
select * from shirts where find_in_set('1','4,5,6,7,8,21,356') <> 0
```

But what issue i have is, i have to match data both side in CSV like below.

```
select * from shirts where find_in_set('1,2,4,5,6','4,5,6,7,8,21,356') <> 0
```

i have data in mysql field i can arrange it in any manner but it will ve CSV only. and i have to search other CSV matching with any value from the other CSV.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of values in your comma-separated strings? Presumably you already know what a terrible idea it is to store CSV strings in database columns, and must live with this situation.

Comment: the maximum number searched will be 6, and yes this is not the best idea, but i am here now. (unplaned)

Comment: You can create a view of a table with csv data in it, then use `IN(4,5,6,7,8,21,356)` or similar to query that view. See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144201/mysql-finding-the-most-frequently-used-words-in-a-comma-delimited-field/47144797#47144797

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM shirts 
WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS( CONCAT('[', '1,2,4,5,6',        ']'),
                     CONCAT('[', '4,5,6,7,8,21,356', ']') )
```

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION shirts.JSON_OVERLAPS does not exist :(

Comment: Add some more information on how this code works or add a link to the library

Comment: @TheRahulJha Maybe you use too ancient version? if your version is not actual then you must specify it at the same beginning of the question.

Comment: @Jbadminton JSON_OVERLAPS is built-in function. It is available since 8.0.17.

Comment: @Akina that doesn't mean you don't need to add additional information. Add a link to the `SQL` function and explain what the function does.

Comment: @Jbadminton What PHP function do you tell about? I do not use PHP code at all in my answer...

Comment: My bad its a `SQL` function. Add the link to the function that is build in. Like this: https://www.sqliz.com/mysql-ref/json_overlaps/ and add some explaination.